# extract part of a string in R

Tags: string, r, extract, gsub

I wonder if you can help me extract a part of a string using R. I have some column d with the following elements :

```
d<-
    [1] Homo sapiens (Human)                                                                       
     [2] Pan troglodytes (Chimpanzee)                                                               
     [3] Pan troglodytes (Chimpanzee)                                                               
     [4] Nomascus leucogenys (Northern white-cheeked gibbon) (Hylobates leucogenys)                 
     [5] Macaca fascicularis (Crab-eating macaque) (Cynomolgus monkey)                              
     [6] Macaca mulatta (Rhesus macaque)                                                            
     [7] Macaca mulatta (Rhesus macaque)                                                            
     [8] Callithrix jacchus (White-tufted-ear marmoset)
```

I want to select every thing before the brackets, i.e the answer would be

```
d<-
    [1] Homo sapiens                                                     
     [2] Pan troglodytes                                                             
     [3] Pan troglodytes                                                              
     [4] Nomascus leucogenys                 
     [5] Macaca fascicularis                           
     [6] Macaca mulatta
```

Thanks

Comment: To use the technical term, you are looking for a substring function

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way in R is to delete everything starting at the parenthesis (including the preceding whitespace, if any):

```
result = sub(' *\\(.*$', '', d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, stringr is a great package.

```
library(stringr)
s <- "Homo sapiens (Human)"

t <- str_match(s, "^(.+)\\s\\(")[2]
t
[1] "Homo sapiens"
```